# Connect Service Error - Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: docusignapi

I have an integration that utilizes the Connect service and we are seeing the error below:

```
Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx :: https://mycompany/ConnectListener/Receiver.ashx :: Error - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.; The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

The web server hosting the connect listener is using a self generated SSL certificate.  Does this have to be a purchased SSL certificate for things to work?

Thank You,

Russell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work with self generated SSL certificates, as you have guessed it does indeed need to be a purchased SSL certificate, even when testing in the DocuSign demo environment (demo.docusign.net).