# Is it feasible to test DocuSign Connect with a self signing SSL?

Tags: docusignapi

We're trying to make sure that DocuSign Connect can ping a URL on our dev environment and we keep getting this message:

(URL)
:: Error - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.; The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I just learned that we have a self-signing SSL certificate set up for the domain. So my question is, while we're trying to get SSL signing set up, is there a way to test with this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This same question has already been answered in this thread:  [Connect Service Error - Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991757/connect-service-error-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-s).

```
It will not work with self generated SSL certificates, as you have guessed it does indeed need to be a purchased SSL certificate, even when testing in the DocuSign demo environment (demo.docusign.net).
```

Answer (score 0):

i've been trying for hours to get this to work with a self-signed cert, same error:

Error - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.; The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.